# unitary operator and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

let V an inner product space over R with a dimention of 3, let $f :V\rightarrow V$ an unitary operator with $det(f)=1$.
prove that if -1 is eigenvalue of $f$ then the characteristic polynomial of $f$ has a linear factors.

I tried consider the situation that $(x+1)(x^2+1)$ is a characteristic polynomial and I tied search for a contradiction, I can't use the fact that $det(f)=1$ that I belive will solve the problem, any help!

Comment: Let $-1, \mu, \lambda$ be the eigenvalues of $f$. If $\mu\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}$, then $\overline{\lambda}=\mu$. In particular, we have $$1=\det(f)=(-1)\lambda\mu=-\vert \lambda\vert^2,$$ which is a contradiction. Can you take it from here?

Comment: If a polynomial has a root $-1$, then it has a linear factor $x+1$.

Comment: @TimurBakiev I think the OP means it factors completely.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven yes, most likely you are right :)

Answer (score 1):

If you consider $f$ as a complex matrix (with real entries), you have eigenvalues $-1,\lambda,\mu$. Then
$$\tag1
1=\det f=-\lambda\mu.
$$
You also know that $\lambda,\mu$ are roots of the characteristic polynomial, which is real; as the other roots is real, since it is $-1$, you have that $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are conjugates, $\mu=\overline\lambda$. Then $(1)$ becomes
$$
1=-|\lambda|^2.
$$
As this is a contradiction, $\lambda$ and $\mu$ cannot be conjugates of each other, which means they have to be real.